# How do I add a trailing # (hash) to a header in GitHub flavored markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a `README.md` markdown file that I use to describe a project that is hosted on GitHub. Within this file I have several headlines and sub-headlines, each starting with one or more hashes, as usual in markdown.

Now I want to set the text of one headline to `C#`, but GitHub does not respect the hash a part of the text, but interprets it as an (optional) closing hash for the headline.

Even if I escape the hash by prefixing it with a backslash, it does not work. So if I type

```
## C#
```

I get:

```
C
```

If I use

```
## C\#
```

I get:

```
C\
```

How do I write this head-line in a correct way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Method 1

You could use a true sharp sign, `♯`, instead of the hash sign, `#`. From the Wikipedia page on C♯:

> By convention, a hash sign is used for the second character in normal text; in artistic representations, sometimes a true sharp sign is used: C♯.

Here `## C♯` produces

### C♯

## Method 2

Alternatively, (at least on this site) just put a space after the last `#`, for example `## C\#` produces

### C#

Note that Pandoc seems to handle `# C\#` correctly ([try it](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try)).

Comment: Thanks. I like using the actual sharp symbol instead. Fresh!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to try is adding another trailing `#` because they act like brackets on the line, so `## C# #` or `## C# ##` if you want to balance out the characters.